# Mail from iSeries with attachment

Tags: ibm-midrange

Is there a way to send an email from an iSeries terminal, adding an attachment from the IFS? I know how to send a normal email using the SNDDST utility.

Answer (score 6):

There is two main methods of doing this.

1. The Do-It-Yourselfer will use QtmmSendMail API
2. Otherwise there are several other free and purchased products that you could use. The ones I would recommend are:

   - [MAILTOOL](http://www.bvstools.com/mailtool.html) - Currently $399. Depending on what you are trying to do, I would recommend [SplTool Suite](http://www.bvstools.com/spltoolsuite.html) if you want to email out spool files.
   - [RPGMail](http://mowyourlawn.com/RPGMail.html) - Free API making use of JavaMail

Comment: While MAILTOOL is still probably the best choice for commercial e-mail software on the i, it is significantly more expensive now, at approximately $300 per year. And it really only shines if you upgrade to Plus, which doubles the cost. It's worth mentioning that this is still relatively inexpensive compared to its competitors, which aren't as good.

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of the operating system come with the [**SNDSMTPEMM**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011153) command already included. It's quite easy to use and allows you to include both a message body and an attachment simply by populating the appropriate parameters.

That is what I would recommend for anyone who has it on their system, and needs something simple and free. For more robustness, there is Brad Stone's [**MAILTOOL Plus**](https://www.bvstools.com/mailtool.html), which is available as a paid subscription.

The below information is my original answer, slightly updated, mainly for historical purposes:

---

Where I work we use [**MMAIL**](http://www.easy400.net/mmail/start). It's low-cost and provides easy-to-use commands.  For example, I happen to e-mail stream files all the time as follows (within a CLP):

```
  MMAIL/EMLSTMF SUBJECT('Monthly Sales Reports') +
    FROMNAME('AS/400') FROMADDR('as400@mycompany.com') +
    TO('jsmith@mycompany.com'/Jim Smith/*TO +
       'bjones@mycompany.com'/Bob Jones/*CC) +
    STMF(&FILE1 &FILE2 &FILE3)
```

There are other parameters available as well (pretty self-explanatory if you use the interactive prompt), and several other commands to handle the most common use cases.  The package does also provide an API if you want finer control, or need to send much more complex messages, but I have never needed more than the provided commands.

This utility used to be free, but the author now requires a "donation" of $50 for full access to downloads from his site.

Answer (score 3):

You could code your own program with Java and the [JavaMail API](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/).

Comment: This is not that hard and has the benefit of only needing a local SMTP-server to forward the constructed email to.

Answer (score 2):

I have not looked in a while but there should be some unixy mail utilities on i5/OS that QSH could use. If not, it's supposedly a simple matter to port one. Look here for ideas: http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.html

But I like the JavaMail idea better. Just a quick google yields a site that has examples of JavaMail usage: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2001/jw-1026-javamail.html

With JavaMail you can also *read* mail if that could also be useful.

**Update**: You say you can already add attachments from the IFS. The command [CATSPLF](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzahz/catsplf.htm) (part of QSH utilities) can retrieve spool files and write them to standard output. Which means you can transfer spool files to the IFS. But you have to know a lot about the job that created them.

Like:

```
    catsplf ... > /my/files/path
```

I found this at http://www.mcpressonline.com/tips-techniques/cl/techtip-read-printer-output-with-qshell.html.
CATSPLF was introduced in V5R3.